Why was Danielle Poole a guest at Danny Stevens' wedding?
The opening episode of season 3 of For All Mankind features the wedding of Danny Stevens in a space hotel. This isn't unreasonable as his Step-Dad owns the place. The inclusion of Ed Baldwin as his deceased Dad's best friend, ex-husband of the other owner of the hotel is maybe a stretch considering the limited guest list possible, but makes sense.
But why is Danielle on the guest list? The two characters barely interact in the episode. I get the narrative desire to set up Dani/Ed antagonistic relationship over the Mars mission command, but I don't see how her presence is justified from a social point of view? At best Danielle and Danny have worked together as astronauts, but do you really bring your boss to a tight numbers event like this?

It turns out that the relationship between Danny and Danielle is deeper than is obvious going into S3E1. Given the way For All Mankind time-skips between seasons this isn't unusual early in the new season.
Episode 3 provides a little more background, when Danny falls of the Wagon and starts drinking again we get a confrontation between Ed and Danielle about the best way to help Danny through, referencing the efforts they both put in to help him the last time.
The For All Mankind Podcast is even more explicit at around 24 minutes when it says;

The episode illustrates the family unit that forms around Tracy and Gordon's absence, Danielle and Ed have circled around young Danny Stevens and become surrogate parents... The work environment has become the spoke around which these things formed.

So, Danielle is at the wedding because she's been like a replacement mother to Danny during the time skip, with their work at NASA, being par.of what draws her, Ed and Danny together as a unit.
